# Explain the Empirical Rule on a dataset 1 to 100?

Tags: normal-distribution, standard-deviation

I'm learning about statistics, so I am still a beginner. I was learning about the empirical rule, but I don't really understand it well. I think that it means that when you calculate the standard deviation, 68% of all data points are within that standard deviation. But when I try this on a simple dataset of 1 to 100:

[1, 2, 3, ..., 97, 98, 99, 100]

The standard deviation would be 50%, right? Can someone explain this to me, and give a good example on how to understand this.

Also, any sources on learning statistics can be left behind in the comment, would be really useful!

Comment: It seems empirical rule is here http://www.statisticshowto.com/empirical-rule-2/. Why call it empirical rule? Obviously, it is theoretical rule.   This rule is applicable to normal distributed random variable. Your case is ideal discrete uniform distribution, and not normal, so cannot use "Empirical rule".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard deviation of those numbers is not "50%", it's about 29; the mean is 50.5. The proportion of values within one standard deviation of the mean would be the number of values between about 21.5 and 79.5, which would be 58 values (out of 100) or 58%.

Can you state what the empirical rule you were given says *in full*, including any conditions? Maybe you missed a condition?

---

(In response to comments)

Here's a comparison (using histograms) of the distribution shape of your set of values and for a (large) sample from a distribution that has roughly the right shape (but isn't actually normal), with a comparison of the proportions within a certain number of standard deviations:

[image: comparison of histograms of a sample consisting of 1:100 and a sample that's the sum of three discrete uniform values on 0:33 (plus 1 to the total)]

Your values gave 58% within 1 sd of the mean and 100% within 2sds.

One the right I have a sample that's over the same possible values, but drawn from a roughly normal-looking distribution; it has 66% within 1sd and 96% within 2 sds -- much closer to what the empirical rule suggests.

Note that the rule is based on population values for a normal distribution,

$\qquad$[image: normal density showing proportions within 1, 2 and 3 standard deviations of the mean]

but it can work okay with samples if the sample's not too small and the distribution shape is reasonably unimodal and not too heavy tailed. If it's close to a normal distribution in shape it tends to work pretty well, especially at the 2sd value.

Your sample doesn't look much like a normal distribution so it's not a big surprise that it wasn't all that close, particularly the 1 sd value

Comment: Is 1-100 a normal distribution? If not, how to see if a collection is a normal distribution?

Comment: Have you got any way of looking at what the distribution shape of a sample might be? (Or even better, of a population distribution, should you know it?) What displays have you learned about? What should a sample from a normally distributed population look like? (It doesn't have to be all that close for the empirical rule to be pretty helpful)